# How to merge 2 data frames filling out missing values in R?

Tags: r, merge, dplyr, plyr

I have been using `dplyr` and the `merge`function for a while, but I just ran into a task that I can't figure out how to do in a simple way. I would like to merge two data frames. The second data frame has some columns missing. I want the output of merge to have these values filled out with the corresponding values of the first data frame.

The data frames look like this:

```
#df1
participant = c(1,2,3)
age         = c(18,23,19)
gender      = c(rep("female",2),"male")
experiment  = rep("noun",3)
rt          = c(218,111,546)
df1         = data.frame(participant, age, gender,experiment,rt)

  participant age gender experiment  rt
1           1  18 female       noun 218
2           2  23 female       noun 111
3           3  19   male       noun 546

#df2
participant = c(1,2,3)
experiment  = rep("verb",3)
rt          = c(238,251,140)
df2         = data.frame(participant, experiment,rt)

  participant experiment  rt
1           1       verb 238
2           2       verb 251
3           3       verb 140
```

This is how the output data frame should look like:

```
  participant age gender experiment  rt
1           1  18 female       noun 218
2           2  23 female       noun 111
3           3  19   male       noun 546
4           1  18 female       verb 238
5           2  23 female       verb 251
6           3  19   male       verb 140
```

**The goal is that** `df2` **is merged using the column participant**, **and the values for the columns age and gender** are taken from `df1`. I have tried many things (all the types of `join`, `rbind.fill`, etc) and I have also looked around in the forum, but I can't find a simple way to achieve binding the rows of the two data frames and filling out missing values in `df2` using a specific column as a reference. In my example, there are only 2 columns to be filled out (age and gender), but my real `df1` has many more, so I would like to avoid specifying them by hand.

If any of you data merging wizards have a suggestion, I would be very grateful!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We place the datasets in a `list`, use `rbindlist` with `fill=TRUE` (from `data.table`), grouped by 'participant, we assign (`:=`) the 'age' and 'gender' as the non-NA values in that column.

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(list(df1, df2), fill=TRUE)[, c('age', 'gender') :=
       lapply(.SD, na.omit) , participant, .SDcols=age:gender][]
#   participant age gender experiment  rt
#1:           1  18 female       noun 218
#2:           2  23 female       noun 111
#3:           3  19   male       noun 546
#4:           1  18 female       verb 238
#5:           2  23 female       verb 251
#6:           3  19   male       verb 140
```

---

Or using only  `base R`, we `rbind` the subset of columns that are common in both the datasets, and then create the additional columns based on the columns that are found in one dataset and not in other.

```
i1 <- intersect(names(df1), names(df2))
res <-  rbind(df1[i1], df2[i1])
nm1 <- setdiff(names(df1),i1)
res[nm1] <- df1[nm1]
res
#    participant experiment  rt age gender
#1           1       noun 218  18 female
#2           2       noun 111  23 female
#3           3       noun 546  19   male
#4           1       verb 238  18 female
#5           2       verb 251  23 female
#6           3       verb 140  19   male
```

Comment: Is there any way to make merge(df1, df2, all = TRUE) work to do this task?

You'll get missing values for age and gender, and the only thing left to do is copy the age and gender values to each observation. Is there a quick way to copy those values for each matching participant.

Nice solution btw.

Comment: @InfiniteFlashChess  I guess you can use the same methodology after `merge`ing to replace the `NA` values as in the `rbindlist` solution.  But, I think `merge` would be slow compared to `rbindlist`

Comment: @akrun: Thanks! I was hoping that there would be some built-in method to do this with `dplyr`, but your `base R` solution works nicely. I think I prefer it over `rbindlist` because it doesn't require specifying the columns to be filled by hand (my `df1` has a bunch of them, not only two, so it could get tedious)